# atomically increment in PostgreSQL hstore like $inc in MongoDB

Tags: postgresql, increment, hstore

New pg hstore looks awesome

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/hstore.html

but it seems do not support atomically increment like MongoDB?

```
db.mycoll.update({mykey: myval}, {my_counter: {$inc: 1}})
```

How to do this with PostgreSQL Hstore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MongoDB needs a `$inc` operator because:

1. Atomic operations in MongoDB are difficult without specific low-level support.
2. The interface isn't rich enough to express `c = c + 1` without a special operator.

You just need to express `c = c + 1` with hstores. This task is complicated a little because hstores use strings for both the keys and values and that leaves you with a mess of casting. I think you're stuck with something nasty like this:

```
update t
set h = h || hstore('my_counter', ((h -> 'my_counter')::integer + 1)::text)
where mykey = myval
```

The `(h -> 'my_counter')::integer + 1` does the increment by extracting the value (`h -> 'my_counter'`), casting it to an integer, and adding one to it. Then you build a single element hstore with `hstore('my_counter', ...)` and an explicit `::text` cast on the value to make sure PostgreSQL knows which function you want. Finally, you concatenate the new key-value onto the original hstore with `h || hstore(...)` to replace the old value.

If you don't want to use that somewhat nasty mess all the time then you could wrap it a simple function and say:

```
update t
set h = hstore_inc(h, 'my_counter', 1)
where ...
```

to hide the nastiness.

I'm sure there are other ways to do it (using the various [to/from array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) functions perhaps) but the above should work.

Comment: hstore in newer version pg is not string anymore, it has native types and can be nested just like JSON.  http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/talks/hstore-dublin-2013.pdf

Comment: @est: As of which PostgreSQL version? The 9.3 docs still say "Keys and values are simply text strings." and all the functions work with `text` and `text[]`.

Comment: @muistooshort You're right. Support for non-string value types is coming in 9.4 (http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/11/Nested-Hstore).